# Magento - get class that dispatched an event

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

Is there a way to get the class in which an event was dispatched in Magento?

You can get the class which is being called using the below code, but is there an opposite function?

```
$observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, I don't think there is a way of doing that.
Events in Magento are dispatched trough `Mage::dispatchEvent()`

The definition of this function can be found in `app/Mage.php` around line 445

```
/**
 * Dispatch event
 *
 * Calls all observer callbacks registered for this event
 * and multiple observers matching event name pattern
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param array $data
 * @return Mage_Core_Model_App
 */
public static function dispatchEvent($name, array $data = array())
{
    Varien_Profiler::start('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    $result = self::app()->dispatchEvent($name, $data);
    Varien_Profiler::stop('DISPATCH EVENT:'.$name);
    return $result;
}
```

And as you can see there is nothing in Magento forcing a class which is dispatching an event to say anything about itself.

Nothing more in `lib/Varien/Event.php` or in `lib/Varien/Event/Observer.php` which are the classes involved in event/observer pattern in Magento.

Although, sometimes, an event may give you `$this` as his data, like in this example :

```
./app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php:222:  
Mage::dispatchEvent('wishlist_item_add_after', array('wishlist' => $this));
```

But there is nothing forcing it in the application design so you never know.